# How to insert the data into Temporary table in Snowflake data base. I have created a DDL:Create temporary table table_name as Select

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

How to insert data into Temporary table in Snowflake data base?
I have already created a table like below:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE mydata.name as
```

Answer (score 6):

Here are some examples which should help.

```
--create a seed table
CREATE TABLE t1 (id NUMBER, str VARCHAR(100)); 

--add records to seed table
INSERT into t1 values (1, 'Rich'), (2, 'Murnane'); 

--this creates the temp table and adds the two records
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t2 AS SELECT id, str FROM t1; 

--this adds additional records, with slightly different data
INSERT INTO t2 SELECT -1 * id, '~'||str||'~' FROM t1; 

--this will show you your four records
SELECT * FROM t2;

ID  STR
1   Rich
2   Murnane
-1  ~Rich~
-2  ~Murnane~
```

Comment: Thank you for the response.

Comment: Hi there @Akhira , if my (or another) answer helps you, please take a moment to "accept" the answer that helped by clicking on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from "greyed out" to "filled in".